# How to check input value is in database or not using laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Iam try to create a inbox message from teacher to parent.

i have 2 teachers (teacher A ,and teacher B) and 1 parent p.

if one teacher(A) enter a message to one parent(p).

and another teacher(B) enter a message to parent (p).

then parent (p) enter  reply to both teachers 2 times.and so on.

Iam Try run code - teacher(a) login and goto inbox page. teacher(A) is only seen teacher(A)-patent(p) last massages,not teacher (B) message.
that work properly.

My controller code is:

```
public function ViewInbox($tid, $id)
{ 
    $parent =WysParent::all();
    $allclass =WysClass::all();
    $teacherid = WysTeacher::where('id', $tid)->first();

    $teachersbjs = DB::table('wys_subjects')
                        ->join('wys_classes', 'wys_subjects.subcls', '=', 'wys_classes.id')
                        ->join('wys_classnames', 'wys_classes.cls', '=', 'wys_classnames.id')
                        ->join('wys_divnames', 'wys_classes.divn', '=', 'wys_divnames.id')
                        ->select('wys_subjects.id', 'wys_subjects.subname', 'wys_classnames.classname', 'wys_divnames.divname')
                        ->where('teacherid',$teacherid->id)
                        ->get();

    $clss = DB::table('wys_classes')
                ->join('wys_classnames', 'wys_classes.cls', '=', 'wys_classnames.id')
                ->join('wys_divnames', 'wys_classes.divn', '=', 'wys_divnames.id')
                ->select('wys_classes.id', 'wys_classnames.classname', 'wys_divnames.divname')
                ->where('clsteacher_id',$teacherid->id)
                ->get();

    $subteacher=WysSubject::find($tid);
    $subcls= $subteacher->subcls;
    $students=WysStudent::where('studcls',$subteacher->subcls)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $msg=array();

    foreach($students as $students)
    {
        $inbox_messages=WysMessage::where('student_id','=',$students->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->first();
        $msg[$students->id]=$inbox_messages['send_msg'];
        $msg[$students->studname]=$inbox_messages['student_id'];
    }

    $students=WysStudent::where('studcls',$id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();

    $inbox_messages = WysMessage::orderBy('id','desc')->get();

    return View::make('teacher.teacher_inbox')
                ->with('id', $id)
                ->with('ltype', 2)
                ->with('teacher', $teacherid)
                ->with('allclass', $allclass)
                ->with('parent', $parent)
                ->with('msg',$msg)
                ->with('students',$students)
                ->with('subteacher',$subteacher)
                ->with('inbox_messages',$inbox_messages)
                ->with('teachersbjs', $teachersbjs)
                ->with('clss', $clss);
}
```

My Problem is Teacher(A) login goto inbox page he/she only view his/her (send / reply) last message.,not all message.

Iam using this code view all teacher(A)-parent(p) messages.

if  teacher(A) and teacher(B) to parent(p) and parent(p) reply to teacher(A) and teacher(B) total messages is 10  in database.

if Send and reply messages total is 5. i wand 5th message.

Comment: So you want to show all messages of specific teacher? Your problem will be probably in view.

Comment: how to show parent(p) view teacher(A) and teacher(b) messages sepretly.

Comment: when parent (p) cilck teacher(a) only view teacher(A) messages not in teacher(b) messages.

Comment: Well it is quiet a mess what you did with a Laravel. Do you know relationships in laravel? You should use it instead you complicated queries.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships